# pass a list of objects via ajax to a MVC controller always sends null

Tags: json, ajax

I am probably missing something very simple.  I have been working on this for a day and an half now and can not get it to work.  I am looping through a table and creating a list of objects to send back to my controller.  For some reason I am always receiving a null value in my controller.  Here is the java script.

```
 var items = [];
        $('#grid tr').each(function () {
            var item = {};
            item.numReceived = $(this).find("input[id*='NumReceived']").val();
            /*skip the header row*/
            if (item.numReceived !== null) {
                item.transactionID = $(this).find("input[id*='item_TransactionID']").val();
                items.push(item);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: './ReceivePOLines',
            type: "Post",
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(items),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function () {
                window.location.replace("../Home/Index");
            },
            error: function (request) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

here is the method signature in the controller

```
 [HttpPost]
  public void ReceivePOLines(List<RecievedTransactions> inTransactions)
```

And here is the class ReceivedTransactions

```
  public class RecievedTransactions{
      public int numReceived { get; set; }
      public int transactionID { get; set; }
   }
```

Here are the results from Fiddler showing what was passed

[{},{"numReceived":"10000","transactionID":"10661768"},{"numReceived":"10000","transactionID":"10661769"},{"numReceived":"2000","transactionID":"10661770"},{"numReceived":"2500","transactionID":"10661771"},{"numReceived":"2500","transactionID":"10661772"},{"numReceived":"2000","transactionID":"10661773"},{"numReceived":"10000","transactionID":"10661774"}]

Any and all help appreciated.
cheers
bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new answer.  Originally, I was getting null, like you.  But, now it works the way you want (array of complex objects).  Please get this to work for you.  If you can't get it to work, although it should, I can create an ASP.NET Fiddle.

```
public class RecievedTransactions
{
    public int numReceived { get; set; }
    public int transactionID { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void ReceivePOLines(List<RecievedTransactions> inTransactions)  // MyArray MyArray
    {
        return;
    }

    //you use your own action name
    public ActionResult Tut133()
    {
        return View();
    }

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut132</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var items = [];
            $('#grid tr').each(function () {
                var item = {};
                item.numReceived = $(this).find("input[id*='NumReceived']").val();
                /*skip the header row*/
                if (item.numReceived !== null) {
                    item.transactionID = $(this).find("input[id*='item_TransactionID']").val();
                    items.push(item);
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                //!!changing your url
                //url: './ReceivePOLines',
                url: "/Home/ReceivePOLines",
                type: "Post",
                cache: false,
                //data: JSON.stringify({ MyArray: items }),
                data: JSON.stringify(items),
                //expecting back from server-need to remove since we are not getting back data from server
                //dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function () {
                    //alerting success instead of opening window
                    alert("success");
                    //window.location.replace("../Home/Index");
                },
                error: function (request) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="grid">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="NumReceived1" value="10000" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="item_TransactionID1" value="10661768" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="NumReceived2" value="10000" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="item_TransactionID2" value="10661769" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Go" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kblau  Thanks I have your solution working.  What I do not understand is why can I pass the associative arrays, but not the array of complex objects?  Do you have any ideas?